# ngModel does not update the variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am creating a log in system using Angular and ionic and I am trying to use [(ngModel)] to connect the variable to update when the field is changing. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_B0iguvXZs&list=PLHrN7HL-00e92ZIz4Fr3-fSh0QyEGLDj8&index=7&ab_channel=BrilliantLabs%2FLabosCr%C3%A9atifs)

```
    export class ModalLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  modal;
  state = "";
  headerText = "Sign Up";

  emailInput;
  passwordInput;
  nicknameInput;

  constructor(public toastController: ToastController, public userAuthService: UserAuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeState("login");
  }

  closeModal(){
    this.modal.dismiss();
  }
submit(){
console.log(this.emailInput);
}
```

this is my HTML code that should be connecting directly to my variable but when I try to print it says undefined

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="login-template">
    <p class="header">{{headerText}}</p>
    <ion-input (ngModel)="emailInput" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
    <ion-input (ngModel)="passwordInput" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
    <a *ngIf="state != 'login'" (click)="changeState('login')" class="change-template-link" href="javascript:;">Already have an account? Click here to login!</a>
    <a *ngIf="state != 'signUp'" (click)="changeState('signUp')" class="change-template-link" href="javascript:;">Don't have an account? Click here to sign up!</a>
    <a *ngIf="state == 'login'" (click)="changeState('forgotPassword')" class="change-template-link" href="javascript:;">Forgot your password?</a>
    <ion-button class="submit-btn" (click)="submit()" color="primary">SUBMIT</ion-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngModel` must be in what is called "Banana in a box".

Try changing it from `(ngModel` to `[(ngModel)]`. [Link](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Comment: When I change it to `[(ngModel)]` I get `ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`

Comment: @YuvalMashiach try adding a `name` attribute. It can be anything. E.g. `<input name="my_custom_input" />`

Answer (score 0):

It not really should be "Banana in a box". But [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) must be there

This is 1 way property binding approach, so as soon as `emailInput` property is changed in a component, ngModel is updated

```
<ion-input [ngModel]="emailInput" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
```

This is 2 way property binding (what you need)

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="emailInput" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
```

And this is 2 way property binding, where you separate property binding from change event (event also can be combined with 2 way ngModel property binding, but sometimes you might need to separate them).

```
<ion-input [ngModel]="emailInput" (ngModelChange)="emailInputChange($event)" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
```

ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute is because you don't have `name` attribute

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="emailInput" name="email" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
```

Comment: When I change it to `[(ngModel)]` I get `ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`

Comment: you need to set, name attribute, see updated answer

Comment: I am still getting the same error now it is just `ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'email'`